# How do I enable push-notification for IMAP (Gmail) using Python imaplib?

Tags: python, gmail, imap

Is there a way to monitor a gmail account using imaplib without polling gmail each time I want to see if there is new mail. Or in other words, I just want the script to be notified of a new message so I can process it right away instead of any lag time between polls.

I see that the IMAP protocol supports this with the IDLE command, but I can't see anything documented with it in the imaplib docs, so any help with this would be great!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There isn't something in imaplib that does this, AFAIK (disclamer: I know very little about Python), however, it seems that someone has implemented an IDLE extension for Python which has the same interface as imaplib (which you can swap out with no changes to existing code, apparently):

https://github.com/imaplib2/imaplib2

Comment: +1 - I was using imaplib recently and found the state of things that you describe.

Comment: The provided link no longer exists. The package can be found on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imaplib2/)

Comment: https://github.com/jazzband/imaplib2

Answer (score 6):

Check out [ProcImap](http://packages.python.org/ProcImap/). It's a more abstract framework on top of libimap and libimap2, providing a nice solution to handle IMAP services. Looks like just the stuff you are looking for, and for me as well. I'm right having the same problem with you and just found ProcImap. Gonna try it for myself.

Comment: wow. this is just what I'm looking for to write client-side filters.

Comment: @evo did this work for you?  I'm also looking to get push notifications about new messages instead of polling.  What function in ProcImap did you use?

Comment: @Alexis I'd guess [`ImapServer.idle`](https://pythonhosted.org/ProcImap/ProcImap.ImapServer.ImapServer-class.html)

Answer (score 3):

This link shows an example of using IMAP IDLE: http://blog.timstoop.nl/2009/03/11/python-imap-idle-with-imaplib2/

It uses the same library linked to in casperOne's answer (imaplib2).

Comment: It's now at https://blog.timstoop.nl/posts/2009/03/11/python-imap-idle-with-imaplib2.html

Answer (score 2):

There is simple [patch](http://bugs.python.org/file27400/imapidle.patch) proposed at [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue11245) implementing [RFC 2177 IMAP IDLE] [3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177) command in a synchronous way ( to wait for more than 1 IMAP server you have to use threads or other means of parallel execution ). It uses stdlib select to wait on socket including timeout. This patch will [eventually](http://bugs.python.org/issue11245#msg171889) be added to stdlib, [but tests have to be written first](http://bugs.python.org/issue11245#msg172383).
The [IDLE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177) command is what you [need](https://blogs.oracle.com/chienr/entry/gmail_supports_imap_idle) for gmail IMAP push-notification.
Hope, this will help :)

Comment: Sadly the patch is still not part of the stdlib. One can use imaplib2 hosted on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imaplib2/) or imapclient hosted on [github](https://github.com/mjs/imapclient/)