# Is there anything in Python that can persistently check to see if an Outlook email with a certain subject title came in?

Tags: python, outlook, alert

I want to know if there's anything in Python that can constantly read my Outlook messages every five minutes. I want it to just check my email every 5 minutes (3:05PM, 3:10PM, 3:15PM, etc.) and as soon as an email comes in my inbox saying with a subject line like "Hello what's up" I want Python to automatically trigger a piece of .py code.

**What I know so far**

I already know how to access Outlook -

```
import win32com.client
win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(1)
...
...
```

**Some possibilities**

I am currently looking at a couple links such as [persistently running Python in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125493/how-to-constantly-run-python-script-in-the-background-on-windows/59126217), [listening for oncoming emails with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513062/how-to-listen-for-incoming-emails-in-python-3), [how to trigger a script upon email receipt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600446/trigger-script-upon-email-receipt) as well as a Youtube video that talks about [how to run a python script upon sending an email.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DRy2aqusl0)

Hopefully I'll be able to figure out exactly how to run my Python script upon receipt of email, but in the meantime this question stays open. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 Hello, apologies, just edited my question - I'm doing some more research to figure this out

Comment: @itprorh66 I was finally able to answer my own question - posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your help. It's been a month, but I revisited this problem and was able to find a solution. While I couldn't find a python program that would listen for an Outlook email, VBA in Outlook could listen for an email and then kick off a python script.

My python code was originally geared to edit an Excel spreadsheet directly. So, when I received an email with a certain subject line `blah` for example,  python file `main.py` would automatically execute and edit an excel file `main.xlsx` accordingly.

Something to note is that `main.xlsx` cannot be open at the time the email arrives. If anyone has any guidance on how to have `main.xlsx` be modified on the chance that the email arrives while it is open, I'd greatly appreciate it.

The below code solved my issue exactly:

```
Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim MessageInfo
Dim Result
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    Debug.Print "Arrived"
    If Item.Subject = "Blah" Then
        Const PyExe = """C:\...\...\...\...\...\python3.9\latest\python.exe"""
        Const PyScript = "R:\...\...\Anders\Python\main.py"
        
        Dim objShell As Object, cmd As String
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        
        cmd = PyExe & " " & PyScript
        Debug.Print cmd
        
        objShell.Run cmd
        objShell.exec cmd
        
        MsgBox objShell.exec(cmd).StdOut.ReadAll
    End If
End If
ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the Outlook Application class fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

In the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171304(v=office.11)) event handler you may get an item instance received and check the Subject property.

You can either process the unread emails in the Inbox (see `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find`/`FindNext`) assuming that new unprocessed messages are still unread or (in case of cached mode) use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Inbox folder - it will fire when your OST file is being synchronized with the remote mailbox.